# Leaflet vertex click event

Tags: javascript, html, maps, leaflet, leaflet.draw

**How to fire/listen a click event from a L.Polygon vertex ?**

The user make a Polygon using:

```
fobDrawPolygon: function(iobMap) {
        var obPolygon = new L.Draw.Polygon(iobMap, {
            allowIntersection: false,
            showArea: true,
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#000'
            }
            //repeatMode: true
        });
        obPolygon.options.touchIcon.options.iconSize = [12, 12];
        obPolygon.enable();
        return obPolygon;
    },
```

and when the polygon is created it is enabled to edit its vertex:

```
onDrawFeature: function(iobMap, iobFeatureGroup) {
        var me = this;              
        iobMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(event) {
            var obLayer = event.layer;
            obLayer.options.editing = {};
            obLayer.editing.enable();
            iobFeatureGroup.addLayer(obLayer);
        });
    }
```

So, the polygon is already drawn and I want to listen the clicks of their vertex

> Leaflet 1.3.1
>
> Plugin Leaflet.Draw
>
> **Notice I don't use control toolbars**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for it I found a lightweight library to control editing of geometries in leaflet:

First, add the *editable* property to the map

```
var map = L.map('map', {
 editable: true,
 editOptions: {…} //not required
});
```

then, to enable feature edition

```
onDrawFeature: function(iobMap, iobFeatureGroup) {
    var me = this;
    iobMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(event) {
        var obLayer = event.layer;
        iobLayer.enableEdit(iobMap); //enable edition            
        me.cacheLayer = iobLayer;
        iobFeatureGroup.addLayer(obLayer);
    });
}
```

And finally listen the vertex clicks of the polygon

```
me.cacheLayer.on({
    "editable:vertex:click": function(e){console.log("You touch me", e)}
});
```

---

Find the library in here:

- [Leaflet.editable API](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable)
- [Leaflet.editable GitHub](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable)

> If someone has another way of doing it, please share it, thank you!